# Why aren't my variables persisting between methods? - iPhone

Tags: iphone, variables, methods, persistence

**Header file:**

```
NSString *righta;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *righta;
```

(I don't usually make @property declarations for my variables but thought this might help the variable persist through the class, though it hasn't)

**Implementation file:**

```
@synthesize righta;

- (void) function1 {
     righta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"];
}

- (IBAction)function2:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"righta is still %@", righta);
}
```

On trying to access the value of the string in the second function, I receive an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and the app crashes.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringWithFormat` returns an autoreleased object. You must retain it. Note that you are accessing the ivar directy, not the property so the string is not getting retained. Use the property instead:

```
self.righta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"];
```

Some programmers prefer to synthesize their properties with a different ivar name to avoid accessing the ivar directly by mistake.

```
@synthesize righta = righta_;
```

Comment: I up-voted all 3 answers, but awarded this one for being the most complete.

Comment: Based on your answer, I assume you could also [righta retain]; and that should work, but the reason properties are preferred is... simply to eliminate unnecessary retain and release calls?

Comment: Yes, that would work too. Properties are preferred because they eliminate boilerplate code encapsulating memory management.

Answer (score 2):

You must use

```
self.righta  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"];
```

To assign the variable otherwise the accessor is not used and the value is not retained.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `[self setRighta:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"]];` Both methods have the same effect (access the setter methods that will do the retaining for you).

Answer (score 1):

Change function1 to:

```
self.righta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"];
```

You were assigning directly to the righta ivar without retaining the string.